# Java Collections API Bug?

Tags: java, collections

I've stumbled upon a bug in the Java Collections API, in Collections.java.

Here’s the code verbatim from the JDK’s source. Just so you know, the JavaDoc version tag reads "1.106, 04/21/06". The method is located in line 638.

```
public static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection<? extends T> coll) {
    Iterator<? extends T> i = coll.iterator();
    T candidate = i.next();

    while (i.hasNext()) {
        T next = i.next();
        if (next.compareTo(candidate) > 0)
            candidate = next;
    }
    return candidate;
}
```

If you take a second to analyse the method, you’ll quickly spot the bug: T candidate = i.next(). D’oh! Calling i.next() on an Iterator without checking hasNext() first? That’s just asking for an exception.

Surely something like that should've been spotted during coding? It means use of the API must check if the collection has at least two elements.

Comment: "It means use of the API must check if the collection has at least two elements." -- Actually, it just means you have to first check if your collection is empty. That's the only case in which that next() would throw an exception.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No - it means that it's invalid to try to find the maximal element of an empty collection. This is specified in the API docs:

```
Throws:
    NoSuchElementException - if the collection is empty.
```

That's what `Iterator.next()` is documented to throw if there's no next element, so it's doing exactly what it's meant to.

Note that *after* the first call to next(), there's a call to hasNext() to check whether there's *more* than one element.

Comment: C'mon, isn't it your bedtime yet? I was just in the middle of saying the same thing.

Comment: surely for a one-element collection, the correct operation is that it should return that element, not throw an exception.

Comment: c'est vrais. i overlooked the while block; something else had caused the excepiton i'd assume.

Comment: @Steeve Reed You are no match for this 32 year - married and father of 3 -google employee - C# book writer guy from Reading, Britain.

Answer (score 7):

Hard to call it a bug since the exception is documented [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection))

Throws:

- ClassCastException if the collection contains elements that are not mutually comparable (for example, strings and integers).
- **NoSuchElementException if the collection is empty.**

Answer (score 2):

According to [API doc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/index.html) *`Collection.max`* method throws *`NoSuchElementException`* if collection is empty.

This is exactly what you observed.